# apache POI issue in formatting

Tags: date, format, apache-poi

I am a newbie in POI and my code is not giving me suitable result. When excel sheet is populating it is not applying style in Date completed column as well as it is not changing the format of the Date completed column to Date **(format should be dd-mmm)** . Here is my code.

```
package oup.excel.report;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPalette;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;

import oup.dbconnection.ConnectionObject;
import util.Mail;

public class CreateExcelReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File reportPath = new File("/a1/reports/");
            reportPath.mkdirs();
            String filename = "/a1/reports/OUP_Delivery_Report_" + getTodaysDate() + ".xls";
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("OUP Delivery Report");           
            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

            HSSFFont font = hwb.createFont();
            font.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 8);
            font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

            HSSFCellStyle style = hwb.createCellStyle();

            HSSFColor CYAN = setColor(hwb, (byte) 204, (byte) 255, (byte) 255);

            style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

            style.setFillForegroundColor(CYAN.getIndex());
            //style.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.BLACK().getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );

            style.setFont(font);
            style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

            HSSFCell jrnlcell = rowhead.createCell(0);
            HSSFCell uidcell = rowhead.createCell(1);
            HSSFCell stepcell = rowhead.createCell(2);
            HSSFCell ptcell = rowhead.createCell(3);
            HSSFCell dccell = rowhead.createCell(4);
            HSSFCell cmtscell = rowhead.createCell(5);

            jrnlcell.setCellValue("Journal");
            uidcell.setCellValue("Unique ID");
            stepcell.setCellValue("Step");
            ptcell.setCellValue("Proof typeset pages");
            dccell.setCellValue("Date completed");
            cmtscell.setCellValue("Comments");

            jrnlcell.setCellStyle(style);
            uidcell.setCellStyle(style);
            stepcell.setCellStyle(style);
            ptcell.setCellStyle(style);
            dccell.setCellStyle(style);
            cmtscell.setCellStyle(style);

            Connection con = ConnectionObject.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT getjrabbr (journalbookid) journal, clientreference UniqueID, (CASE WHEN currentstageid = 11 THEN 'GALLEY' WHEN currentstageid = 1 THEN 'PROOF' WHEN currentstageid = 54 THEN 'FROM T/S' WHEN currentstageid = 2 THEN 'REV1' WHEN currentstageid = 3 THEN 'REV2' WHEN currentstageid = 4 THEN 'REV3' WHEN currentstageid = 14 THEN 'REV4' WHEN currentstageid = 18 THEN 'REV5' WHEN currentstageid = 19 THEN 'REV6' WHEN currentstageid = 20 THEN 'REV7' WHEN currentstageid = 21 THEN 'REV8' WHEN currentstageid = 70 THEN 'REV9' WHEN currentstageid = 71 THEN 'REV10' WHEN currentstageid = 6 THEN 'Supply Files for QA' WHEN currentstageid = 93 THEN 'Resupp QA' WHEN currentstageid = 39 THEN 'PAP' WHEN currentstageid = 99 THEN 'PAP1' WHEN currentstageid = 100 THEN 'PAP2' END) step, tsp Prooftypesetpages, TO_CHAR (CLIENTUPLOADDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') Datecompleted FROM v_jobitems_history ji WHERE ji.clientid = 1487 AND CLIENTUPLOADDATE IS NOT NULL AND CLIENTUPLOADDATE BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) + 3 / 24 AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 3 / 24 order by 5";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            int i=1;

            HSSFCellStyle style1 = hwb.createCellStyle();
            HSSFFont font1 = hwb.createFont();
            font1.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
            font1.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 8);

            style1.setFont(font1);
            style1.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style1.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style1.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style1.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style1.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

            CellStyle cellStyle = hwb.createCellStyle();
            CreationHelper createHelper = hwb.getCreationHelper();
            // Set the date format of date
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("d-mmmm"));
            cellStyle.setFont(font1);
            cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

            CellStyle cellStyleInt = hwb.createCellStyle();
            cellStyleInt.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#"));
            cellStyleInt.setFont(font1);
            cellStyleInt.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyleInt.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyleInt.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyleInt.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);          
            cellStyleInt.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

            while(rs.next()){
                String journal = rs.getString("journal");
                String UniqueID = rs.getString("UniqueID");
                String step = rs.getString("step");
                String tsp = rs.getString("Prooftypesetpages");
                String Datecompleted = rs.getString("Datecompleted");

                System.out.println("journal : " + journal);
                System.out.println("UniqueID : " + UniqueID);
                System.out.println("step : " + step);
                System.out.println("tsp : " + tsp);
                System.out.println("Datecompleted : " + Datecompleted);
                System.out.println("================================================");

                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);

                HSSFCell jcell = row.createCell(0);
                HSSFCell ucell = row.createCell(1);
                HSSFCell scell = row.createCell(2);
                HSSFCell tcell = row.createCell(3);
                HSSFCell dcell = row.createCell(4);
                HSSFCell ccell = row.createCell(5);

                tcell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

                jcell.setCellValue(journal);
                ucell.setCellValue(UniqueID);
                scell.setCellValue(step);
                if(tsp!=null && !tsp.equals("")){
                    tcell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(tsp.trim()));
                }else{
                    tcell.setCellValue(0);
                }

                SimpleDateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");

                String reformattedDt = null;
                Date inputDt = null;
                try {
                    reformattedDt = newFormat.format(oldFormat.parse(Datecompleted));
                    inputDt = newFormat.parse(reformattedDt);                   
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dcell.setCellValue(inputDt);
                ccell.setCellValue("");

                jcell.setCellStyle(style1);
                ucell.setCellStyle(style1);
                scell.setCellStyle(style1);
                tcell.setCellStyle(cellStyleInt);
                dccell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                ccell.setCellStyle(style1);

                i++;
            }

            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                }
                if(pstmt!=null){
                    pstmt.close();
                }
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
                sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) j);
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            hwb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            Mail mail = new Mail();
            boolean sendmail = mail.sendMailWithAttachHtmlFormat("dbadmin@aptaracorp.com", "abc@abc.com", "abc@aabc.com", "OUP daily delivery report", "<p style='color:blue'>Hi, <br/>Please find the daily delivery report for the articles.</p><br/><p style='color:blue'>Thanks,<br/>Aptara Automailer</p>", filename, "", "DBADMIN");
            if(sendmail){
                System.out.println("Mail sent successfully.");
            }
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
        } 
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            if(fnf.getMessage().indexOf("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process")>=0){
                System.out.println("The file is already being used by another process. Please close the file and try again.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Exception occured : " + fnf.getMessage());
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getTodaysDate(){
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf;               
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_hh_mm_ss");
        String dtString = sdf.format(date);
        return dtString;
    }

    private static HSSFColor setColor(HSSFWorkbook workbook, byte r,byte g, byte b){
        HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();
        HSSFColor hssfColor = null;
        try {
        hssfColor= palette.findColor(r, g, b); 
        if (hssfColor == null ){
            palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.LAVENDER.index, r, g,b);
            hssfColor = palette.getColor(HSSFColor.LAVENDER.index);
        }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return hssfColor;
        }
}
```

Please give me a proper solution.

Thanks

Saikat

Comment: @Sankar: please reply on urgent basis

Comment: Are you able to create a shorter code snippet that shows up the same problem? Say, one which only deals with a single date cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your HSSFCell `dcell` to store your date values inside your while loop.  However, this cell's style is never set.

Your line

```
dccell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

inside your while loop is setting your header cell's cell style ("dccell"), not your actual date value cell's style ("dcell").